# Android - Command not found

Tags: android, linux, classpath

I am trying to run the command in ubuntu

> android update project --path .

However I am getting a `android:command not found error.`

I assume this is something to do with the path which I learnt on here the other day? I was just wondering, what do variable do I need to add (Android I assume) and what do I need to point it too.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

On MacOS/Linux, define the path to wherever you installed your SDK as `ANDROID_HOME`:

**MacOS**

```
$ export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/android-sdk-macosx
```

If you installed [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), the value will need to be

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
```

**Linux**

```
$ export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk-linux
```

Then add the paths to the `platform-tools` and `tools` sub-directories (Same on MacOS/Linux).

```
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

You should now be able to run `android` from the shell.

If none of the suggested ANDROID_HOME paths above are valid, you can find the (uniquely and consistently named) platform-tools folder via:

```
find / -name platform-tools 2>/dev/null
```

Whatever path that returns will need to be trimmed down to end with either `sdk`, `android-sdk-linux`, or `android-sdk-macosx`.

Comment: Hi @Mati i do not understand your question

Comment: when I do what You've written everything works untill I restart. After that I got "android command not found".

Comment: @Mati This means that your export settings are just stored temporaly. On which OS are u working?

Comment: I installed Android Studio from developer.android.com/sdk/index.html with the default options and the value for ANDROID_HOME needed to be `export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: @mmmm see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11709409/1596547 about how to add these settings permanent on linux

Comment: I did the same but still it shows command not found! I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: please try it again. It supposed to work. redo everything from begining

Comment: Here also says for "android" command not found, but other commands from the directory are working. I did a chmod 777 on the android executable but still not in path. I can execute it in the folder by using ./android. Anyone a pointer for this weird behaviour?

Comment: @mmmm copy the code to ~/.bash_profile.Then, "source ~/.bash_profile".You can use adb command permanently.

Answer (score 26):

Another possibility is simply that your "android" file is not executable. Navigate to the tools path in terminal and then make it executable by:

`chmod 777 android`


Then you can run:


`./android sdk`


It's what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for including the "./" before android sdk.  Not everyone realizes that has to be there.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you have set `ANDROID_HOME` to point to the sdk install, you should add `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` and `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes even after you add your `android_sdk/` dir path from command line it still doesn't work and gives the `command not found error`, in that case follow these steps. I ran through this issue myself and i tried all the above steps and none worked so i thought i should share and perhaps that might help somebody. 
( **android-sdk-linux is the name of android sdk library which you have extracted** ).

1) Open the bashrc file from command line

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

2) Add following lines at the top.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

3) Log out of the system and log back in. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open command line and type **android** to launch the software.

Comment: Logging out & back in is required to get the OS to read .bashrc into memory. As a shortcut, you can just tell the OS to read the file again with:
source ~/.bashrc
(same as) . ~/.bashrc
(both assuming the file is in your home directory ~/ )

Comment: source ~/.bashrc will update the environment vars in the terminal/tab you run it in. If you are working in another tab (that was already open when you ran source ~/.bashrc), then you have to run it there too or open a new tab so that it has the updated references.

Answer (score 2):

After installing [Android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html).
Create or edit your ~/.bashrc file and add the following lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
```

and reload .bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `platforms` and `platform-tools` are not in the `PATH` environment variable. You can run the `adb` command with `path-to-adb/adb` or add `platforms` and `platform-tools` to  `PATH` and run typing only `adb`

This is my path environment variable:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.5.3:/opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools:/opt/android-sdk-update-manager/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

For Mac, go into your home directory by typing `cd ~`, and then type `vi .bash_profile`, This file might be empty or just created, and this is not a problem.

To edit the file, press `i` on your keyboard and inside the file, type the following path:

```
export PATH="/Users/YOUR-USERNAME-HERE/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
export PATH="/Users/YOUR-USERNAME-HERE/Library/Android/sdk/tools":$PATH
```

When you are done, press `esc`, and again press `shift :` and type `wq`. Okay, now you saved your file. Now, quit terminal and re-launch, and try typing:

```
adb -h
android -h
```

If both commands are giving you output, it means everything works fine.

Not: We used `vi` command to edit the file. If you got confused with this command, you can also try `nano` for editing the file.

Answer (score 0):

android is now inside android-sdks/tools

if you are using mac, you may set your .bash_profile to include it.

```
PATH=$PATH:[android-sdks]/platform-tools:[android-sdks]/tools
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall cask android-platform-tools

   ```
   brew cask uninstall android-platform-tools
   ```
2. Install it using Android Studio