# change PATH permanently on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, path

I'd like to add to PATH the value ":/home/me/play/"
for the installation of Play! framework.
so I ran this command:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/me/play
```

it worked. but in the next time I checked, the value changed back to the old one.

so I guess I didn't "saved" the new value, right?

how do you do that?

Comment: You may reconsider having a longer `PATH`; on Ubuntu, if `$HOME/bin` exists it is added to your `PATH`; I would suggest adding all your executables to your `$HOME/bin` instead. Perhaps you should reconfigure and rebuild your `Play!` framework. Having very long `PATH` (or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) is by experience a nightmare.

Comment: Belongs on ———> http://askubuntu.com

Comment: @VladLazarenko: why not [unix.SE.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) ? (I don't quite get what the difference is)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Add

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/play
```

to your `~/.profile` and execute

```
source ~/.profile
```

in order to immediately reflect changes to your current terminal instance.

Comment: and `source ~/.bashrc` to immediately reflect changes.

Comment: Generalize a little -- add that line to whatever profile file is correct for your use case.  `~/.bashrc` isn't applicable if you use another shell, or if you need the changes to be reflected in non-login bash shells and other complexities.

Comment: As tripleee points out combining `export` and assignment into one command only works on Bash.  For POSIX compatibility write it as two commands.  Also, to make this into an explicit command: `echo "PATH=$PATH:/home/me/play; export PATH" >> ~/.profile; . ~/.profile`

Comment: Can somebody explain what happens after each line? What does `source` command do?

Comment: Read commands from file and execute them in  the  current  shell
       environment.

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` won't work on Ubuntu, because `~/.bashrc` is called by `~/.profile` file, not the other way round. Use `source ~/.profile` instead.

Answer (score 87):

Add the following line in your `.profile` file in your home directory (using `vi ~/.profile`):

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/me/play
export PATH
```

Then, for the change to take effect, simply type in your terminal:

```
$ . ~/.profile
```

Comment: +1: This is more correct than `.bashrc` because `.profile` is read by all Bourne-compatible shells out of the box.

Comment: @tripleee but `.profile` requires reboot, right ? (it didn't work for me, and I have way too many apps opened to reboot)

Comment: You can `. ~/.profile` for the changes to take immediate effect in your current shell.

Comment: @tripleee: damn, how could I miss that part of the answer! Sure it works. Sorry for disturbance.

Comment: `echo $PATH` to verify the change.

Comment: on Ubuntu this (`$ . ~/.profile`) worked while `source ~/.bashrc` had no effect

Comment: This one worked for me in ubuntu 16

Comment: Outstanding. Adding stuff to `~/.bashrc` didn't work for me but doing to `~/.profile` indeed works even with bash. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what will be the path to drive which is mounted? mean the drive else than home. Because as I saw the drive have the some random number each time. `72f9f0ae-7f8c-486b-9f5f-bc34efb74005`. THen the path could be lost on each restart.

Comment: @Alex Log out and log in, not reboot, to have the changes take effect. Sourcing .profile works only for the current shell.

Answer (score 8):

Try to add `export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/play` in ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil it must be `~/.bashrc`, with a leading `.`

Comment: it works for now, I assume that I need to restart my machine to know for sure.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to add this path for all users on the system, add the following line to your `/etc/profile.d/play.sh` (and possibly `play.csh`, etc):

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/me/play
export PATH
```

Comment: `export VAR=value` is a Bashism; you want to separate the assignment and the export to two separate commands for POSIX compatibility.

Comment: NO need for it to be executable. the file is 'sourced', not 'executed'