# I change the PATH in ubuntu but it doesn't work

Tags: bash, ubuntu, path

I installed Intellij Idea in my ubuntu.And I run it from the terminal.

First [I do it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709374/change-path-permanently-on-ubuntu),change the PATH into .bashrc,and also source it.

but it doesn't work.

And I'm sure the directory is correct.
Now I write a alias in .bashrc it works.

```
alias runidea='cd $THEDIR ; sh idea.sh'
```

I echo the PATH it's correct.but if I type `sh idea.sh`

it tells me `sh:Can't open idea.sh`

Comment: is idea.sh in $THEDIR ? That's a requirement for the alias you have created.

Comment: it's and the alias work,but the PATH doesn't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try just run it by typing `idea.sh` into your shell (without `sh`)

like `$ idea.sh` not `$ sh idea.sh`

Comment: if I go to its directory it work.and the alias work.But the PATH doesn't work.

Comment: if idea.sh is in your $PATH,and it has executable permission,then you can run it by `idea.sh` without `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alias runidea='~/idea-IU-111.277/bin/idea.sh'
```

Now the alias is created and then run the following command

```
runidea
```

idea-IU-111.277 can be replaced by your intellij idea folder