# Trouble in Setting Java Environment Path on Ubuntu (libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, java-home

Found the solution!

Ubuntu by default ignore the command "RD_LIBRARY_PATH" therefore I need to add those codes in ".bashrc" instead of "/etc/environment" or .profile.

it now work perfectly fine!

---

I am trying to run a program that reads Java method from C/C++ code. (I made it on Windows successfully, now, I am working on Linux)

I made it successfully compiled and run on Ubuntu, however, the problem is..
Whenever I try to run the program, I have to type following commands on terminal..

```
source /etc/environment
./invoke #program name is invoke
```

If I do not type "source /etc/environment" every time I boot my PC, the error message I get is...

```
error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Ok. Here is what I added in /etc/environment

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25_x64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25_x64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

What I want is that, as you know, I want to run the program without typing "source /etc/environment".
I also tried typing those PATHs on /etc/profile, but result was same... I should type "source /etc/profile" every time I reboot my PC..

How to make it permanently applied to whole range of System without typing "source /etc/environment" stuffs everytime I boot?

if you need to see source code of the program, here is downloadable address:
http://cfile237.uf.daum.net/attach/247819495212DF1C07B9EB

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, but that's *not* how `/etc/environment` woks on Ubuntu. It's not a script file to be sourced which is why what you have in there doesn't work on boot / login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

Ubuntu by default ignore the command "RD_LIBRARY_PATH" therefore I need to add those codes in ".bashrc" instead of "/etc/environment" or .profile.

it now work perfectly fine!

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

**For x86:**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386/server
```

**For x86_64**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of setting the path(permanently) however I was using Red Hat, If you look [change PATH permanently on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709374/change-path-permanently-on-ubuntu) it might help you. There was a file on Red Hat **.profile** that once you add your exports statements, they will get loaded when the computer starts. :) There should be the kind of file for ubuntu

```
export     PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25_x64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25_x64

Comment: Ok. tried to write things in "~/.profile" However it was same. I had to type ". ~/.profile" everytime I reboot to make it work, otherwise it does not work.. well the problem is if I do not type ". ~/.profile"  and then type "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH", it shows nothing. however, if I type ". ~/.profile" then it shows PATH written in "~/.profile"

Comment: I suppose that you edited .profile or .bash_profile depending on which one you have, this would give you an idea.vi .bash_profile 
add: export [VARIABLE]=/variable/path/
        export PATH=${VARIABLE}/bin:$PATH
Then esc :wq Enter

Answer (score 0):

Put "-Djava.library.path=FULL_PATH_HERE/jre/lib/amd64" as a JVM option in your C code.

Edit the full_path_here part.

The path is allowed to be relative, but I don't think you can use $JAVA_HOME as a placeholder for the environment variable.

Comment: Xabster > I am sorry It didn't work. I changed corresponding C code to options[0].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25_x64/jre/lib/amd64/server"; but it did not work.

Comment: Xabster > it also did not work after I changed /etc/environment to "export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25_x64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25_x64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25_x64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25_x64/jre/lib/amd64/server"

Comment: Please confirm that the libjvm.so file is in the amd64/server folder. I didn't expect it to be there, but I could be wrong. I don't understand the last thing you tell me. What did you change in etc/environment that made it stop working? I'm trying to give you C-code that will allow the JVM to find the libjvm.so file without you changing global environment variables. Please also confirm that you're getting the same error since you removed the java.class.path VM option.

Comment: Yes, libjvm.so file is in amd64/server folder. yes, same error occured.

Answer (score 0):

1. add the path of the missing libraries in the file /etc/ld.so.conf
2. execute the following command: ldconfig
   this way, you'll add the new libraries to the default ones.
3. To check whether the new libraries have been linked,
   execute the following command: ldconfig -p
   to have the list of libraries currently linked by default.