# install rJava - "configure: error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type"

Tags: java, r, java-native-interface, rjava

I have came across this problem while installing rJava on R3.0.1:
"configure: error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type"

The detailed message is attached below.
I searched for similar problems but my issue is a little trickier and many proposed solutions either didnt work or I could not try, because I am working on a server which I do not have write access to system libraries.

**OS**: Linux 2.6.18-348.6.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue May 21 15:44:27 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux (info given by typing "uname -a" sorry I couldn't quite understand this info)

**R**: R3.0.1, I downloaded the source, put in my home directory, and built R from source.

**rJava**: I ran 'install.packages("rJava")', during installation I got:

=========================

checking Java support in R... present:

interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'

archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'

compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'

header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'

cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/jre/../include -

I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/jre/../include/linux'

java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/se

rver -ljvm'

checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes

checking JNI data types... configure: error: One or more JNI types differ from the 
corresponding native type. You may need to use non-standard compiler flags or

a different compiler in order to fix this.

ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'

* removing '/home/me/R-3.0.1/library/rJava'

==================================

Since I can only access the server remotely, I do not have write access to anything outside my home directory /home/me.

Any information would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi
I got help from our local server admin team and I thought it'd be useful for me to update.

The problem was when I was building the rJava package it is getting confused between the default version of Java on the server (usr/lib) and the custom version that I installed in my /home area. The latter was set by the .bashsrc file which has lines like:

<br>export JAVA_HOME=/home/me/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java
<br>export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/jdk1.7.0_04/bin 

so once I removed those two lines rJava installs properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same problem trying to `install.packages("rJava")` in R version 3.0.2, as long as I tried to install as ordinary user (Linux, Debian).  There was no problem running `install.packages("rJava")` as root.  Then, trying `library(rJava)` worked for root but not for me as a user:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/usr.local.original.Debian/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This problem required to add the environment variables `JAVA_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` 
to `~/.login` (following instructions found at [Trouble in Setting Java Environment Path on Ubuntu (libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326412/trouble-in-setting-java-environment-path-on-ubuntu-libjvm-so-cannot-open-share)):

```
setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server

# For c-shell; for bash, it would have to be:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

So, you would have to have a system administrator install rJava for you, then set your environment variables and, of course, set your own `.libPaths()` in R such as to find rJava.

Answer (score 7):

I hit the same issue on my mac OSx El Capitan. I tried updating the java paths/envs used by R using "R CMD javareconf" with no effects.

Finally, I saw that when I ran "R CMD javareconf" my Java library path: in the output was empty. By digging up further I figured out that my JAVA_HOME was not set correctly as pointed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3311983 . I had to add an extra /jre in the JAVA_HOME path.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me on El Capitan.
After I installed it, I got an error when loading the package which I solved by doing:
sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
as in [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite#answer-31039105) question.

Answer (score 2):

Using linux, specifically, 64 bit Gentoo, my solution was to add the following line to **/etc/env.d/20java-config**

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/etc/java-config-2/current-system-vm/jre/lib/amd64:/etc/java-config-2/current-system-vm/jre/lib/amd64/server"
```

Then

- Run **env-update**
- **source /etc/profile**
- start **rstudio** (or if you are using GUI menu, logout and login to load the environment)

The above change needs to be made by root but then will apply to non-root users who use the same system, on next login.

Basically, rJava conf test was failing to find libjvm.so, the conftest program would compile but not link :)

Comment: As of 2021, this does not work aymore (on 64 bit Gentoo).