# rJava configure error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type

Tags: java, r, macos, rjava

A priori my question might seem duplicated based on the title, but I have tried all answers in similar questions and I have not managed to solve the problem.

I am on a mac 10.11.5, on `R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-16)`.

My java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

and in my `.bash_profile` you will find:

```
# Java
export JAVA_HOME="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`"
```

so that:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
```

**PROBLEM**

Trying to use `coreNLP` or `xlsx` I obtain the following error messages:

```
> initCoreNLP()
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error in rJava::.jinit() : JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

> require(xlsx)
Loading required package: xlsx
Loading required package: xlsxjars
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1
```

**FIX ATTEMPTs**:

1-based in what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179151/cannot-load-r-xlsx-package-on-mac-os-10-11) I did:

```
$sudo R CMD javareconf
....
....
JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

And then I tried to install it using both:

```
install.packages("rJava",type='source')
```

and dowloading rJava from [here](https://www.rforge.net/rJava/files/) and:

```
 R CMD INSTALL rJava_0.9-9.tar.gz
```

The two returned:

```
checking JNI data types... configure: error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type. You may need to use non-standard compiler flags or a different compiler in order to fix this.
```

2- based on what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530601/install-rjava-configure-error-one-or-more-jni-types-differ-from-the-corresp) I added this line to my `.bash_profile`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/server
```

where:

```
$ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/
Xusage.txt    libjsig.dylib libjvm.dylib
```

but it has not worked either, still the exact same error.

3- I have also tried to simply simlink:

```
sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

and again did not work.

At this stage, the only thing for me left to try is based on [this](https://oliverdowling.com.au/2015/10/09/oracles-jre-8-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/). Where they suggest to download `jre-XXX-macosx-x64.tar.gz` and replace the existing `jre` directory as explained in the post.

However, before "jumping" to do that, I was wondering if someone is experiencing or has experienced the same issues with a similar configuration and has managed to solve it. 
Thanks

**UPDATE**

I solved the issue by removing the line:

```
 export JAVA_HOME="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`"
```

from `.bash_profile`.

No idea why, but worked.