# cannot open shared object file while running kivy example

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

I have installed kivy on ubuntu. While running the examples, I am getting this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
     from jnius import autoclass
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jnius/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
     from .jnius import *
 ImportError: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: make sure you are using the python that comes with kivy and make sure you paths and environment reflect this ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley : can you please tell me how to do that? I am new in it.

Comment: it is easiest if you use an IDE that supports project environments (like eclipse or pycharm) ... you will need to follow the directions in your IDE ... but just make sure its pointing to the python in `/whatever/kivy/python/...` and then you will need to set your path variable as well, and I think iirc correctly kivy also needs to know a couple of other variables ... Im pretty sure kivy has a tutorial on setting up your kivy developement environment

Comment: did you follow these instructions http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu?

Comment: yes i did followed all instructions. my examples inside demo folders are running but outside of the demo folder are not running and giving me this error.

Comment: it looks like you probably just need to add the path where libjvm.so lives. (in the java directory) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326412/trouble-in-setting-java-environment-path-on-ubuntu-libjvm-so-cannot-open-share or http://stdioe.blogspot.com/2012/08/libjvmso-cannot-open-shared-object-file.html

Comment: yes i checked that already before adding this as question but didnt yet got solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention exactly which example you are running, but this example uses pyjnius, which means that it is probably meant to be run on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error using javabridge and the error occurred in the file jutil.py when trying to import _javabridge. I think this could be a common error when calling java in python projects.

The key here is to find the 'lost' **libjvm.so** file. It should be somewhere in your **jdk** directory. Then add to your path when you run your program. (Sorry, not familiar with jnius)

(FYI. I was on a linux machine so I did `find ./ -name "libjvm.so"`in my usr/java/jdk1.7 directory and found its location. Then, in my case, I configured the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7/jre/lib/amd64/server`.)