# Where is PATH variable set in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, path

This is a very interesting question that I stumbled upon when I was creating a command-line application tool for Linux. Unfortunately, the answer on SO is so hidden among the myriad answers to other questions that I decided to ask another question on SO for those who want to modify PATH programmatically.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709374/change-path-permanently-on-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: This is not a duplicate. He's asking where the path is set. Not how to set it himself. I want to know the same answer, since something in Ubuntu is adding multiple folders multiple times to the path, and it's not me. Thankfully, the answers to this question is providing me the info I need (even though it was copied from the duplicate... <sigh>). Suggestion: Remove the duplicate marking, and reword the question name to be more clear?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[Grzegorz Żur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962251/14955) to another question captures it brilliantly. Unfortunately it was hidden away among many other answers.

> There are multiple ways to do it. The actual solution depends on the
>   purpose.
>
> The variable values are usually stored in either a list of assignments
>   or a shell script that is run at the start of the system or user
>   session. In case of the shell script you must use a specific shell
>   syntax.
>
> ### System wide
>
> 1. `/etc/environment` List of unique assignments. Perfect for adding system-wide directories like `/usr/local/something/bin` to `PATH`
>      variable or defining `JAVA_HOME`.
> 2. `/etc/xprofile` Shell script executed while starting X Window System session. This is run for every user that logs into X Window
>      System. It is a good choice for `PATH` entries that are valid for
>      every user like `/usr/local/something/bin`. The file is included by
>      other script so use POSIX shell syntax not the syntax of your user
>      shell.
> 3. `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/*` Shell script. This is a good choice for shell-only systems. Those files are read only by shells.
> 4. `/etc/<shell>.<shell>rc`. Shell script. This is a poor choice because it is single shell specific.

Also, `/etc/environment` is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Since this file stores the system-wide locale and path settings, it is most oft quoted choice.
Using `/etc/profile` is not preferred. It exists only to point to `/etc/bash.bashrc` and to collect entries from `/etc/profile.d`

> ### User session
>
> 1. `~/.pam_environment`. List of unique assignments. Loaded by [PAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962251/14955) at the start of every user session irrelevant if it is an X
>      Window System session or shell. You cannot reference other variable
>      including `HOME` or `PATH` so it has limited use.
> 2. `~/.xprofile` Shell script. This is executed when the user logs into X Window System system. The variables defined here are visible to
>      every X application. Perfect choice for extending `PATH` with values
>      such as `~/bin` or `~/go/bin` or defining user specific `GOPATH` or
>      `NPM_HOME`. The file is included by other script so use POSIX shell
>      syntax not the syntax of your user shell. Your graphical text editor
>      or IDE started by shortcut will see those values.
> 3. `~/.profile` Shell script. It will be visible only for programs started from terminal or terminal emulator. It is a good choice for
>      shell-only systems.
> 4. `~/.<shell>rc`. Shell script. This is a poor choice because it is single shell specific.

Comment: Why have you c+p an answer from the duplicate question ?

Comment: There are around a million questions on SO that plays around this topic. I asked this question because it could lead developers quickly to this answer which is complete and informative...

Comment: The question you took this answer from is far more complete and informative...

Comment: And yet it is still linked, if someone requires further information

Answer (score 10):

For temporary change:

```
~$ export PATH=$PATH:~/root/scripts
```

For permanent change, you can add this line to the `/etc/environment` file like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/root/scripts
```

Comment: and then 
source /etc/environment