# Permission error [Errno13]Permission denied while installing robotframework-SikuliLibrary

Tags: python

I have a Linux machine with Ubuntu rel 20.10, I'm using the robot framework with Eclipse. I have a problem with a Sikulilibrary
doesnt'work. I tried to `pip install robotframework-SikuliLibrary`,

But i have this error

```
> Exception : Initializing test library Sikulilibrary with no arguments
> failed:Permission error[Errno13]Permission denied
```

I tried to install Selenium library all is ok,do you have any questions about this issue?

Robotframework 3.2
Python 3.8.6

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Maurizio and welcome to StackOverflow. I have seen that you have not yet accepted an answer. Both myself and Metal3d have answered, if you found those answer helpful you could **upvote** them, and you could also **accept** what you think is the definitive solution to your problem, whilst you could add comments if you think the problem was not solved. Please have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are adding the module in the correct Python installation (your Python 3.8 and not the system Python) and that you are installing in your home directory. This way no special permission will be needed.

```
pip3 install --user robotframework-SikuliLibrary
```

The above will install the package in the user site-packages directory of the current (running) Python. In my case it is `~/.local/lib/Python3.9/site-packages`, which is already in my `PATH`. It should be the case for you too, so you should be good to go.

Otherwise, if you have problems like `ModuleNotFoundError` just find your `site-packages` directory with:

```
python3 -m site
```

You will have it under `USER_SITE`. Take note of it and add it to `PATH` following help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676849/where-is-path-variable-set-in-ubuntu) question.

Otherwise, like @Metal3D said, you could use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Answer (score 0):

`pip` wants to install the package in your system, and you don't have the right to write here. But... **Do NOT use `sudo` with `pip`**. This will install system-wide and can break your installation or a package can overwrite this one.

Use virtualenv, or pipenv.

E.g. To use virtualenv:

```sh
cd your-project
python -mvenv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
# and then
pip install XXX
```

You will need to call `source .venv/bin/activate` anytime you want to work and launch your project. The behavior is to change the installation path to a local path (and not your system).

Or, like said @BIOS in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66785567/1472048 comment, use your "home" installation with "--user" option to install in `~/.local/lib`.