# solana install on Ubuntu - where is it installed to?

Tags: solana

I tried to follow steps both
a. https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

```
(base) xxx@xxx:~/dev/nft/metaplex/metaplex/js/packages/cli$ sudo sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.8.1/install)"
                                                           [sudo] password for xxx: 
                                                           downloading v1.8.1 installer
                                                           Install is up to date. 
                                                           1.8.1 is the latest compatible release

                                                           Please update your PATH environment variable to include the solana programs:
                                                             PATH="/root/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"
```

I updated $PATH, but no joy. I got no installation error but command prompt can't find solana.

b. I then also tried steps here
https://snapcraft.io/install/solana/ubuntu#install

```
(base) xxx@xxx:~/.local/share$ sudo snap install solana --beta --devmode
                               solana (beta) 0+git.ca12fac from Michael Vines (mvines) installed
(base) xxx@xxx~/.local/share$ solana --version
                               solana: command not found
```

Where was solana installed to actually? I can't find it.

Comment: Just checking. You did run `source .bashrc` for the changes to kick in right?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, the setup script that you ran in the first step installs the solana CLI in `$HOME/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/` and then adds it to your `PATH` in `$HOME/.profile`.

As an easy fix, you can logout and log back in to pick up the change.

Comment: In my case I had forgotten to add that to path so I had to edit my `~/.zshrc` file and add `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/"` at the end, then I saved the file and ran `source ~/.zshrc` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue comes from that you updated the $PATH variable in wrong location.

In many cases, we have two options `/home/[username]/.bashrc` and `/home/[username]/.profile` to update the $PATH variable.

When I was installing solana tool suite, I updated the `/home/[username]/.profile`.
In other word, I inserted `export PATH="/home/[username]/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"`  at the end of `.profile`.
And it worked.

I think you should try this way if you didn't yet.

About the options of terminals(bash, etc) and $PATH variable, I recommend to take a look at [Where is PATH variable set in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676849/where-is-path-variable-set-in-ubuntu)