# Current file path where an env variable is located

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I need to know where my actual env variable is stored.

If I do `echo $PATH` it outputs this:

/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/myuser/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts

Which path does this env variable come from?

I need to know the exact file path, not all probable possible paths.

I'm using Ubuntu.

I already check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532155/linux-where-are-environment-variables-stored) but my question is different, I do not need to know where the var is stored in memory, but in which file on disk. When the pc is shutted down, afaik nothing remain in the memory (ram), so after reboot the os reads these vars somewhere and put them again in memory. So these vars are stored in a file (like .bashrc or another one), not only in memory.

So, where is its file path?

I don't want to use a "casual" file path for editing my $PATH env, I want to edit where it is set.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain, why this https://stackoverflow.com/a/532161/7733418 (one of the answers in the proposed duplicate) does not explain what you need to know. I.e. why do you doubt that environment variables are not stored in files, are instead stored in process-specific memory, can be visualised in (virtual) file system in different ways and can be made persistent by resetting them after each restart/reset in automatically executed scripts, like in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. I am afraid that otherwise (even if this gets reopened) this question will quickly be closed again.

Comment: Apart from that, please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Because I suspect that you intend to do something with the file you are trying to find, but that the reason for doing that can better be replaced by something else. For that please take one logical step back and ask for help with what you are trying to achieve by/through/after finding "the file which stores your environment variable". Or to put it differently, which environment variable are you working on and what do you want to do once you found the file it is stored in?

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for your comments, I updated the question. Let me know if now it is more clear.

Comment: May I recommend to rephrase and remove the assumption that the content you see in PATH variable is coming from a (single) file from which it is reloaded? Maybe something like "Where is the content of PATH environment variable come from?" I do not know the answer, but I suspect that it will be a) not reading from one file b) not contradict the explanations in the duplicate c) be more useful for you. You  might end up with answers listing diverse init and setup scripts/executables which concatenate values into the variable. My guess is "lots", but you might get the most common ones.

Comment: Searching for my proposed phrasing I get https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash Does that help? Or Ubuntu-specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676849/where-is-path-variable-set-in-ubuntu

Comment: I still would like you to consider the XY problem and/or tell us what you want to achieve in the next step.

Comment: I find your question pretty unclear: _know where my actual env variable is stored_ : Every environment variable is stored in, well, the _environment_ of a process. Perhaps you want to  _know where my actual env variable has been set_? Since you are responsible for setting your variables, you should know this better than me, but: If I would have to research at a foreign accounts, where variables get their values, I would first open a new login shell _with tracing_, i.e. `bash -xl`, and analyze the output . Either I can see immediately from the output, where it happesn, or I can debug from here.