# -bash: android: command not found on Mac OSX

Tags: android, macos, bash

I've been diving into Android development for a while, and now I want to use some project (helpshift) in my app. On the website they have some [example apps](http://developers.helpshift.com/android/samples/) in which the readme says: Run the following inside the /HelpshiftDemo folder.

```
android update project -t android-17 -p .
```

So I do this, but unfortunately this gives me an error saying `-bash: android: command not found`. I understand this, because "android" as such doesn't refer to anything on my laptop (Mac OSX). So I thought it is maybe referring to the adb. So I tried replacing `android` for the direct path to my adb:

```
/Users/kramer65/dev/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk/platform-tools/adb update project -t android-17 -p .
```

This gives me a humongous output with more information on adb, which is I guess not the expected result.

So my questions; what does `android` refer to, and how can I fix this on Mac OSX?

Comment: You should consider giving this guy a check mark if it answered your question or at least write your own answer.

Comment: @jQwierdy - You are absolutely right. Just did it.. :)

Comment: linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969753/android-command-not-found

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The `android` tool is located in the `tools` directory in your SDK. You need to add this to your `PATH` environment variable so that bash can recognize it.

You can do this by adding it to your `PATH` in your `.bash_profile` file. This file should be located in your home directory. Create if it doesn't exist using `vi .bash_profile` and add the following line to it:

```
export PATH=<path_to_android_sdk>/platform-tools:<path_to_android_sdk>/tools:$PATH
```

where `<path_to_android_sdk>` is to be replaced with the path to your SDK. For example: `"/Users/me/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools"`

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! Of course you have to make sure that you remove the '<' and '>' as well as the text. My path was /Users/my_user_name/android-sdks so my total added to my .bash_profile was literally: 
export PATH=/my_user_name/android-sdks/platform-tools:/my_user_name/android-sdks/tools:$PATH

Comment: This worked for me previous, but with the last update to OS X Mavericks it stopped. I still see the entries in the PATH, but adb cannot be resolved. It works if I run it locally via ./adb but not with just 'adb'.

Comment: I have to added following Line : 
export PATH=/User/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/User/username/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
restard my terminal, but still not working :( help

Comment: oops , my fault - I had to write Users instead of User in the path ^_^ it works perferct

Comment: Does this still work in Catalina? I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 31):

**Step 0**

The first step is install Android SDK: https://developer.android.com/studio

I don't like the default configurations. I installed SDK in this folder:

```
/Users/<Username>/Android\ SDK
```

ℹ️ The default path is

```
$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
```

**Step 1**

The next command open your bash or zshrc configuration file:

Bash profile:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

If you use zsh:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

**Step 2**

You're ready to update your configurations:

```sh
# File: .bash_profile | .zshrc

# Custom path to Android SDK folder. 
# If you use the default configuration please change ANDROID_HOME to $HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<Username>/Android\ SDK
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

**Step 3**

**Option 1:** 
Restart your terminal and you should be able to use `android` command

**Option 2:** source your `bash` or `zsh` profile.

Example: `source ~/.bash_profile` / `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: I installed Android Studio from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html with the default options and the value for ANDROID_HOME needed to be `export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: Do you see my comment? "# !!! Change this configuration path. I install Android SDK in my local Mac directory."

Comment: I see your comment and raise you the information needed for a default Android Studio install. Telling people they need to change it doesn't tell them what to change it to or how to find the answer. I'm just trying to help people out. It's not an indictment. It would be useful to tell people they can find the (uniquely and consistently named) platform-tools folder via `find / -name platform-tools 2>/dev/null` and the parent folder will be the sdk/ANDROID_HOME path.

Comment: thix this worked perfectly for me! just for reference, this is what i added to my .bash_profile and then restarted the terminal:

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH

Comment: Great but restarting terminal wasn't enough for me, I needed to run `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Add information for bash and zsh. @PhilHudson thank you very much.

Comment: In 2018, the Android SDK install path on OSX is /Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: This should no longer be a top answer, this path is out of date and not correct.

Comment: @Eduardo thank you very much for the commend and for the feedback. I've updated my answer. Do you think the current version is helpful ?

Answer (score 23):

I spent so much time trying to figure out, this steps helped me ( from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html )
You need to execute your `.bash_profile` to update your `PATH`.

## Set up your PATH environment variable on Mac OS

Open the Terminal program (this is in your Applications/Utilites folder by default).
Run the following command

`touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile`

This will open the file in the your default text editor.
You need to add the path to your Android SDK platform-tools and tools directory. In my example I will use "/Development/android-sdk-macosx" as the directory the SDK is installed in. Add the following line:

`export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools`

Save the file and quit the text editor. Execute your `.bash_profile` to update your PATH:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Now every time you open the Terminal program you `PATH` will included the Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you! This actually helped me get it working. The other answers were probably correct but this helped me identify what I was doing wrong and was also much simpler to set up!

Comment: Awesome this is the best way to correct the problem and the simplest. This  also highlighted a new issue. I installed Android Studio and updated through the SDK manger within the IDE. After following your instructions and getting the _'android'_ command to work it brought up another SDK manger view that showed the API's i previously updated in Android Studio were not actually updated. Not sure how I have two SDK instances or where that disconnect is.

Answer (score 11):

**Problem Solved For Android Studio Users:**

I am using Mac OS X Elcapitan version 10.11.X.

Under my home directory I found ***.bash_profile.save*** file. I opened that file using sublime (you can use any other editor). Then I added this line

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/UserName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/UserName/Library/Android/sdk/tools
```

Replace "**UserName**" with your UserName.

open terminal then run

```
 source ~/.bash_profile
```

here  you go.

Answer (score 6):

First add these lines to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

then:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

```
export PATH="/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/":"/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/tools/":$PATH
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Add the following lines into ~/.bash_profile and source ~/.bash_profile

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk/
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

This is working for me

Answer (score 2):

Update the path.

Open the Terminal program from Spotlight. Run the following command:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

Then save following code

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```

For my case, path is

```
export PATH=/Users/<user-name>/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/<user-name>/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools:$PATH
```

Save the file and quit the text editor. Execute your .bash_profile to update your PATH:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then run adb.

Answer (score 2):

This is the issue because of you didn't give proper android sdk path variable in .bash_profile. for this you must follow the below steps.
1. Check android sdk path: for this you should open android studio->preferences and click on Android SDK in newly open window in that look for Android SDK location textfield in that you can find path of Android SDK. For me it shows like: `/Users/<your_name>/Library/Android/sdk`. here `<your_name>` is name of your home directory.
2. Open your terminal enter `cd ~` command.
3. and enter `vi .bash_profile`.
4. In vi editor enter following
`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Murali/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH`
Save it by press `esc` button and enter `:wq`.
5. After this close your terminal and open it again.
6. To apply all your changes in `.bash_profile` enter following command
`source .bash_profile`.
7. Enter `android` command. Hope this now working fine :-)

Comment: adb command is working but android 'command not found' occurs

Answer (score 0):

Update the path.

Open the Terminal program from Spotlight. Run the following command:

```
touch ~/.zshrc (or ~/.bash_profile) ; open ~/.zshrc (or ~/.bash_profile)
```

Then save following code

```
export AAPT_HOME=/Users/****/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0
export PATH=$PATH:$AAPT_HOME
```

Save the file and quit the text editor. Execute your .zshrc (or .bash_profile) to update your PATH:

```
source ~/.zshrc (or ~/.bash_profile)
```