# How to get Android command line tools to work?

Tags: android, macos

I cannot figure out how to get my Android command line tools to work. I had run the following commands, but when I type in Android avd, the output is `bash: android: command not found`. Does anyone have any advice on how to get the Android command line tools to work? I have installed the SDK, etc. I am not sure what to do.

```
export Android_Home=/Users/username/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Comment: I assume you're using a Mac, have you seen [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832803/bash-android-command-not-found-on-mac-osx)

Comment: I can't find .bash_profile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One obvious problem with this:

```
export Android_Home=/Users/username/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

...is that `Android_Home` is not the same as `ANDROID_HOME`. Environment variable names on Mac OS X (and other Unix systems) are case-sensitive. Try:

```
export ANDROID_HOME= ...
```

Next, in a comment OP wrote:

> I can't find .bash_profile

Well, you just have to create it under your home directory. Open a Terminal, and type:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Additionally, I think in

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools
```

... the `/tools` bit is too much. SDK home should be just `/Users/username/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/`, then in `PATH` you want to have `$ANDROID_HOME/tools`.

Comment: I got it to work. Once I took @Jonik's advice and changed to tools, not platform_tools. Thanks everyone!

Comment: export Android_Home=/Users/username/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools 

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

android updated project -t 1 -p . 


above lines worked for me...

Answer (score 4):

This is working on my osx system. Apply your paths correctly.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/nathansire/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Remember to run source to apply changes from ~/.bash_profile

```
source .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

export Android_Home=/
Users/username/Downloads/
adt-bundle-mac-
x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:
$ANDROID_HOME/tools

to

export ANDROID_HOME=/
Users/username/Downloads/
adt-bundle-mac-
x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:
$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools