# android command is not found in mac terminal

Tags: android, bash, macos, terminal, command

I have seen many answers but could not understand much as most voted answer for similar topic uses vi which i don't know. Second answer is still simple to understand but i encountered one problem. It opens .bash_profile which contains python so should i overwrite this file or create a new one? I hope you have understood the problem.
Thanks in advance for help. 
[Answer i was referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832803/bash-android-command-not-found-on-mac-osx).

Comment: You need to add an additional line to your bash profile, don't delete anything that is currently in there, just add the android block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android` command line tool is **no longer supported**.

You should instead use Android Studio to [create AVDs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html) and [create projects](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project.html).