# android: command not found

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I tried to make a `.jar` file from a cloned project:

```
android update project -p .
```

but got the error:

> android: command not found

I tried to set path to Android SDK, but it didn't help:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=D:\java\android-sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME\tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME\platform-tools:$PATH
```

Is it possible to solve this problem?

UPD:
I'm using Git Shell from this software: http://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: Are you using cygwin? Please update your post with information about your environment.

Comment: @AntonSavin, the post is updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969753/android-command-not-found)

Answer (score 24):

**Finding-android-sdk-on-mac-and-adding-to-path**
[Finding Android SDK on Mac and adding to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532063/finding-android-sdk-on-mac-and-adding-to-path)

To fix

> android: command not found error

follow two easy steps (Linux and Mac):

1) Export your Android Sdk path to the ANDROID_HOME variable

> $ export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk

(change "~" to "$HOME" on Mac)

2) Export Sdk tools path to the PATH variable

> $ export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH

That's it! run

> android

command again to make sure it works properly.

Comment: This worked for me, though my actual path variables were a little different (`$Home/Developer/android-sdk-macosx`).

Comment: @jose920405 Did you try $HOME instead of ~ for android sdk path? It worked on my mac.

Comment: For people over here who are still struggling, Iran V gave hints and it would better if you locate your Android SDK folder by yourself. Like for me it was located in /Users/bachiri/Library/Android/sdk and normally the android executable file should be in the tools folder.
literally, the exact path that I should add to to the $PATH variable is  /Users/bachiri/Library/Android/sdk/tools =>$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools

Answer (score 13):

You have to configure ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

For Mac Run this command

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

For Windows

Go to Control Panel → System and Security → System → Change settings → Advanced System Settings → Environment variables → New, then enter the path to your Android SDK.
Variable name = ANDROID_HOME
Variable path = your android sdk path.

Answer (score 7):

If you run commands from windows shell (cmd.exe) you should add `D:\java\android-sdk\tools` and `D:\java\android-sdk\platform-tools` to your path via computer properties dialog.

If you run on Cygwin try `export PATH=/cygdrive/d/java/android-sdk/tools:/cygdrive/d/java/android-sdk/platform-tools:${PATH}`.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me  on **ubuntu**

Edit the bashrc using nano:

`nano ~/.bashrc`

By adding the following to the end of the file:

`export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk`

`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools`

Exiting the nano editor:

`ctrl + x` , then type `Y`, then hit the `enter key` to save the changes to the `.basrc` file and to exit the nano editor.

The above steps would ensure that your changes remains after the terminal closes. Note, for the `android` command to work ensure to **close the terminal and reopen a new one**.