# [Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]

Tags: android, cordova, path

I am trying to build an android application on Mac OS X by using cordova. 
When I execute cordova build I get the following error :

[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Just missing the variable from your path.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216928/android-command-not-found-in-new-terminal-window/30217362#30217362 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969753/android-command-not-found for setting your path variable up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: ANDROID\_HOME is not set and android command not in your path You must fulfill at least one of these conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful)

Comment: The answer is in [Setting ANDROID_HOME environmental variable on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19986294/2334082).

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the path of Android SDK

**Windows:**

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

**Mac OS x**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Here you have a similar question:
[Setting ANDROID_HOME enviromental variable on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x)