# Android Studio Terminal: Command not found

Tags: android, variables, android-studio, terminal, path

I would like to run the following command in my Terminal of Android Studio.:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

I am getting the issue:

```
Command not found.
```

I have already read that I have to [add the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216928/android-command-not-found-in-new-terminal-window) somehow. 
But I do not understand how it should be done...

I am running Android Studio 2.2 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Add the path in your **Environment Variables**. The link you are referring is for Linux systems and not Windows.

Comment: I looked up the Android SDK path in Android Studio >> Settings >> Appearance & Behavior >> System Settings >> Android SDK and added it to the Windows variable Path. Restarted Andriod Studio but still getting the same issue. Is the path correct? C:\Users\jublikon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: You mentioned you have add SDK path into the Windows variable Path, but the adb command is under SDK\platform-tools, have you add this directory and restart ?

Comment: An installer that does not define its environment variables is a perfunctory and lukewarm installer. This is clearly a bug in the installer of the Android Studio "complex"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a system variable:
[image]

Add it to Path:
[image]

**Adb** is located under platform-tools:
[image]

Comment: Broken links, images won't display.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mac or linux, you can try like this

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Now Check

```
adb status
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify your system environment and instead keep the changes local to Android Studio, do this:

1. Goto Settings -> Tools -> Terminal
2. Add `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` to "Environment variables". Separate multiple variables with semicolon (`;`) or use the GUI tool (Shift+Enter). Modify the path to point to your SDK installation as needed.
3. Change "Shell path" to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "set "PATH=%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools;%PATH%" "`

**Notes:**

- `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is used for the installation directory of the SDK according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables).

Answer (score 0):

if you are still getting same error,simply go to your sdk location in terminal and type cd platform-tools .Then start doing what you want to do.adb works here. :)